# Importing huge dataset (around 36 GB and 18000 columns, csv) into R

Tags: r, bigdata

I got data from UK Biobank and wished to import it into R for further cleaning and data analysis.

But it could not work.

I tried package data.table and ff. Both failed because of insufficient memory.

My compluter is 16 GB windows 10.

I also tried SQLiteStudio. It failed because data have too many columns so that SQLiteStudio could not import them.

Would you mind giving me some suggestions about the following steps?

Thank you so much and wish you keep healthy and happy during this special time!

Comment: You can have a look at `disk.frame` package

Comment: R generally loads data into memory. If your data is 36GB and your memory is 16GB, then you will have to look for solutions that use disk space, not memory. If you plan to subset your data down so it fits in memory, then the `vroom` package may help.

Comment: Thank you so much,Frank!@FrankZhang   disk.frame package works.

Comment: Thank you, Gregor! @GregorThomas It seems vroom package should work. I will test it later.